# How to Update Data Without Button

Tags: android, timer, android-volley, fetch, updatable-views

I need a help how to update data through the website in android application. I have fetched the data through a website, but I have no any idea or example for changing the data automatically.

The Data Change On Restarting Application Or Onclick Through. Please tell Me How to update data automatically.

***MainActivity.java***

```css
package com.example.exampleproject;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String showUrl = "http://wap2mob.net/rand.php";
TextView example;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
example = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
showUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
System.out.println(response.toString());
try {
JSONArray success = response.getJSONArray("success");
for (int i = 0; i < success.length(); i++) {
JSONObject succes = success.getJSONObject(i);
example.setText(succes.getString("random"));
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
System.out.append(error.getMessage());
}
});
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
}
```

***activity_main.xml***

```css
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.exampleproject.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/example"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[See OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dt7D.png)

Comment: can you tell me when exactly did you want to update your application data ? When you change some data into website or what ?

Comment: i want to update random value in my application without restarting app. or without click.

Comment: hmm you must use some type of socket or timer , and after (for example 1 min) to update your api call or  your UI, but this is hard work and app can be slower after time of using. This i got in my mind now,but must be other way to achive your goal.

Comment: which method used in google cloud massanging or whatsapp

Comment: must be some type of socket comunication for sure...